# grails 3.1.3 accessing a validatable helper class directly as a controller call

Tags: grails

Something has changed in the recent version of grails:

This call to [index](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/wschat/WsChatController.groovy#L47) had always worked up till 3.1.3

```
def index(ConnectTagBean bean) {
        if (wsconf.enableSecurity) {
            redirect(controller: "${controllerName}",action: "auth${upperCaseFirst(actionName)}")
            return
        }
        renderIndex(bean)
    }
```

Now when I run the plugin I hit this issue, it is unclear but it seems related to this:

```
grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.validate(Validateable.groovy:82)
```

The entire trace:

```
Grails application running at https://localhost:8443 in environment: development
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - AbstractMethodError occurred when processing request: [GET] /wsChat/index
grails.plugin.wschat.beans.ConnectTagBean.validate(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Map;[Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Z. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: grails.plugin.wschat.beans.ConnectTagBean.validate(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Map;[Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Z
    at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.validate(Validateable.groovy:82)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - AbstractMethodError occurred when processing request: [GET] /wsChat/index
grails.plugin.wschat.beans.ConnectTagBean.validate(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Map;[Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Z. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: grails.plugin.wschat.beans.ConnectTagBean.validate(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Map;[Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Z
    at grails.validation.Validateable$Trait$Helper.validate(Validateable.groovy:82)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

The browser shows this message:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/wsChat/index
Class
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
Message
null
Caused by
grails.plugin.wschat.beans.ConnectTagBean.validate(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Map;[Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Z
Trace
    Line | Method
->> 1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by AbstractMethodError: grails.plugin.wschat.beans.ConnectTagBean.validate(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/Map;[Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Z
```

At the moment the chat plugin seems to be broke and it would be a lot of work to take all of that out and in short it means introducing inconsistencies between 2/3 plugin to another extent again.

Is there an easy fix ?

Comment: It might be worth trying to upgrade to Grails 3.1.4, which was released earlier today. I don't know if it will fix your problem, but it does address bugs with Validateable features. (see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues?q=milestone%3Agrails-3.1.4)

Comment: thanks but the issue still persists with 3.1.4

Comment: Thank you @jnunderwood. To try re-create issue I made a very basic app under 3.1.4 and it worked. I think even though I had initiated everything under 3.1.4 including a new test app the gradle.properties of the plugin was still pointing to the older grails and must have been causing the issue. This issue is now resolved